# CSS li bullet does not show when li is inline-block

Tags: html, css

When letting li to be inline-block, bullet points do not show anymore.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: circle;
}
ul.columns>li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 1cm;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Vertical</h1>
<ul>
  <li><a class="openPage">Besoins en magnésium</a></li>
  <li><a class="openPage">Besoins en azote</a></li>
</ul>

<h1>Horizotal is missing bullets</h1>
<ul class="columns">
  <li><a class="openPage">Besoins en magnésium</a></li>
  <li><a class="openPage">Besoins en azote</a></li>
</ul>
```

See my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/stephanedeluca/9xdkp3q7/2/

Comment: Bullet points or list style icons works only for `display: list-item` applied elements. This property is applied by default to the `li` element, which you are overriding now by applyineg `display: inline-block`. Hence, the list style icons will be gone.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not the nicest way of doing it for sure. But I do recall this not really having any other conclusive outcome..

```
ul.columns>li:before { content:'\ffed'; margin-right:0.5em; }
```

EDIT: I understand the answer is already posted, but one uses absolute positioning and is less effective overall in my opinion and the other is over complicated also, not sure why relevant positioning is required on it? Plus the spacing is already sorted for you via this way. And it's only 2 attributes, simpler.

Comment: \ffed which type of code it is ? For disc type bullet whats the code ?

Comment: it's a hexadecimal unicode character starting with an escape character. Try \2022.

Answer (score 16):

Bullet points or list style icons works only for `display: list-item` css property applied elements. This property is applied by default to the `li` elements, which you are overriding now by applying `display: inline-block`. Hence, the list style icons will be disappeared.

It seems you are trying to get the two li elements adjacent to each other. Well, in that case, you should definitely use `display: inline-block`. and then use pseudo class with display as `list-item`. That will solve your problem.

```
ul.columns>li:before{
    content: "";
    display: list-item;
    position: absolute;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/9xdkp3q7/4/)**

Comment: This is interesting as well. Though, on my very own case, (actual app), the bullet point is a bit to high-positioned. Is there a way to shift it a but downwards? @Mr_Green

Comment: @StéphanedeLuca try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9xdkp3q7/5/) and let me know..  if it is bit high then give `margin-top` in negative value.

Comment: @Mr_Green you definitely saved lot of hours for me

Answer (score 4):

When you first create a list, the default `display` value is set to `list-item`. When you change it to `display: inline-block;` it is no longer recognized as a list item.

Here are some sites that have good information on lists:

-http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-lists/#declaring-a-list-item

-http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/list-style/

Answer (score 1):

You can manually add the bullets to the `:before` :psuedo-element.

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: circle;
}
ul.columns>li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 1cm;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
ul.columns>li:before {
  content: '◦';
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-weight: bold;
  top: 1px;
  left: -3px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Vertical</h1>

<ul>
  <li><a class="openPage">Besoins en magnésium</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="openPage">Besoins en azote</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<h1>Horizotal is missing bullets</h1>

<ul class="columns">
  <li><a class="openPage">Besoins en magnésium</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="openPage">Besoins en azote</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```